Sources for the Noncontradiction principle in Judaism
IMU, the "Law of Noncontradiction" does not apply in religion in general - same rabbis can hold opposing views and contradicting Halochos can coexist (see אֵלּוּ וְאֵלּוּ דִּבְרֵי אֱלֹהִים חַיִּים, Eruvin 13).
My question is whether some sources for the existence of such a principle can be found in the scripture or Rabbinic literature?

In the sense you've described, the Law doesn't apply in science either. Scientists frequently have opposing views and until it's sorted out, scientists would need to take both into account. Even in an actual situation, see Schoedinger's Cat: we take into account that the cat is both dead and alive. - In the more normal understanding that someone is not allowed to contradict himself, Judaism certainly does apply this Law, all the time.

בראשונה לא היתה מחלוקת בישראל, אלא על הסמיכה בלבד (Yerushalmi Chagiga 2:2). See also https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Sanhedrin.7.1?lang=he, https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Sanhedrin.1.4.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he

@MichoelR You're right, my bad. I wrote the question and then tried to beef it up with a preface that wasn't successful. I'll rewrite it, but the question stays.

@MichoelR I've edited the question, you can delete the comments.

אלו ואלו only means each one is partially correct.

The law is basic logic, and is set out by the Ramchal in his work on logic. https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaHiggayon.15.1?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en

@N.T. An interesting idea, can you elaborate on it, please?

Put it this way: If John sees and describes the western face of a mountain, and Jim sees and describes the eastern face of said mountain, their descriptions might be very different although each is entirely correct. Their different viewpoints might lead to very different conclusions about said mountain, and one may be right and the other wrong in their conclusions, but both descriptions have value and are true from their perspective. For an in-depth discussion, see https://www.amazon.com/Dynamics-Dispute-Makings-Machlokess-Talmudic/dp/0910818991

I believe that, contrary to your assertion that the Law of Noncontradiction does not exist in Judaism, it is in fact fundamental to the entire Talmud.
For example, just on Yoma 14b, which I happen to have studied recently, it appears four times.

The Gemara derives from the Mishna that in the daily service in the Temple, first the incense was burnt, and afterwards the Menorah was cleansed of ashes that had accumulated.  It questions how this can be, given that it contradicts a Mishna elsewhere (in Tamid) which gives the opposite order.
In response to the answer of Rav Huna, who asserts that unattributed Mishnayos in Tamid follow the views of Rabbi Shimon Ish Hamitzpeh (and therefore represent a different opinion than unattributed Mishnayos in Yoma), the Gemara asks how this can be.  A beraisa in Tamid has Rabbi Shimon Ish Hamitzpeh arguing against the view of an unattributed Mishna there; thus we see that he is not the author of unattributed Mishnayos there.
Following (but not in response to) the answer of Rabbi Yochanan, who asserts that unattributed Mishnayos in Yoma follow the view of Rabbi Shimon Ish Hamitzpeh, the Gemara questions an apparent contradiction within Yoma itself.  On the one hand, the local Mishna puts the incense prior to the cleansing of the Menorah. On the other hand, another Mishna in Yoma puts the cleansing of the Menorah first and the burning of the incense afterwards.
In response to Abaye's answer, that first five arms of the Menorah were cleansed, then the incense was burnt, then the remaining two arms of the Menorah were cleansed (thus, each Mishna refers to one part of cleansing the Menorah), the Gemara asks how could this be.  Abaye seems to contradict himself, for he says elsewhere that the sprinkling of the blood of the Daily Offering, not the burning of the incense, was in between the two stages of cleansing the Menorah.

Much Talmudic argumentation takes this form.  Some statement X is quoted or proposed.  The statement is questioned because it contradicts a more authoritative source, or because the rabbi that proposed it thereby contradicts himself--that is, at face value, statement X violates the Law of Noncontradiction.  Then, either a resolution is found, or else statement X is abandoned.
The Gemara in Eruvin which you reference says the following:  Rabbi Abba declared in the name of Shmuel, for three years Beis Shammai and Beis Hillel debated.  Each said "the halacha is like our opinion."  Finally, a Bas Kol (Heavenly Voice) emerged and said that both these and those are the words of the Living G-d, but the halacha is like Beis Hillel.
It seems clear from this that in fact the halacha cannot be self-contradictory.  While both Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai found favor in Hashem's eyes, and one who studies the words of either is credited with studying Torah, the practical halacha must follow one or the other.
I do not know what source you think you have for the assertion that one rabbi can hold two contradictory opinions.
